# Retrieving multiple rows dynamically using Pivot in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I wish to add multiple rows for a particular pivot table.

Table name : MasterTable

```
 FieldName | FieldValue
------------------------
 Field1    | F1value1
 Field2    | F2value1
 Field3    | F3value1
 Field1    | F1value2
 Field2    | F2value2
 Field3    | F3value2
```

Expected result:

```
Field1     | Field2    | Field3
---------------------------------
F1value1   | F2value1 | F3value1
F1value2   | F2value2 | F3value2
```

I tried this code but result me with only one row.

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(FieldName) from MasterTable FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
    set @query = 'SELECT  ' + @cols + ' from (select FieldName, FieldValue from MasterTable ) x
                pivot 
                (
                    max(FieldValue)
                    for FieldName in (' + @cols + ')
                ) p '

    execute(@query)
```

Output:

```
Field1     | Field2    | Field3
---------------------------------
F1value1   | F2value1 | F3value1
```

Could someone please help me to have multiple rows using pivote table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the subquery, use:

```
(select FieldName, FieldValue,
        row_number() over (partition by FieldName order by FieldName) as seqnum
 from MasterTable
)
```

`pivot` will take this into account in the pivoting.

Note:  This will guarantee the number of rows, but the ordering of each column is *arbitrary*.  You may want to replace the `order by` with a reasonable column for ordering.

Comment: it worked but shows null values in between

`
Field1     | Field2     |Field3
F1value1 NULL NULL
F1value2 NULL NULL
NULL F2Value2 NULL
NULL F2value1 NULL
NULL NULL F3Value
NULL NULL F3Value2
`

Comment: @Roshmi . . . I left out the `partition by`.  The updated version will fix that problem.

Comment: can you please help me once more. I found a problem in displaying the values. it was showing different order. in 1st column 1st row it shows "F1Value1" and then 1st Column 2nd row "F1Value2" but when comes to the 2nd column 1st row it shows "F2Value2" and 2nd column 2nd row shows "F2Value1" . I need all the "Value1" as 1st row and "value2" as 2nd row. for that i have also added a new field to the table "RowOrder" which will specify the order to the pivote table. but i couldnt find a solution.

Comment: @Roshmi . . . New questions should be asked as new *questions*.